# update parameter in Java Primefaces

Tags: primefaces

My problem is kinda tricky, I hope u get my explanation, I'll be as clear as I can with this.

I have a DataTable that displays a button to see the activities related with the selected item.  this opens a little panel with a menu, that at the moment has only one option. This opens yet another panel with 2 forms, in with I do what I need to.

My problem comes when I use the update parameters to add the info I need into the DB.

this is the code for the button I'm using.

```
<p:commandLink action="#{reporteConsultorBean.verActividades(lead)}" update=":formMain:panelViewNotas" title="Ver actividades asociadas al Expediente">
   <center>
       <p:graphicImage value="/images/actividad32.png" />
   </center>
</p:commandLink>
```

this is the dialog that pops out once you clicked the button.

```html
<p:dialog id="idDialogActitividades" header="Actividades del Expediente" 
            widgetVar="dialogActividades" resizable="true" 
            showEffect="slide" hideEffect="fade">               
                    <center>
                        <p:panel header="Actividades del Expediente" >                          
                            <p:panelGrid columns="1">
                                <p:commandLink title="Notas" onclick="dialogNotaView.show(); return           false;" style="margin:0 auto">
                                    <center>
                                      <p:graphicImage value="/images/nota.png"/>
                                    </center>                                           
                                </p:commandLink>                                
                            </p:panelGrid>
                            <br/>
                            <p:panelGrid columns="1" >
                                    <p:commandLink title="Cerrar" onclick="dialogActividades.hide(); return false;" style="margin:0 auto">
                                                <p:graphicImage value="/images/cerrarBoton.png"/>
                                    </p:commandLink>
                            </p:panelGrid>
                        </p:panel>
                        <br />
                </center>
</p:dialog>
```

and this is the form in which you save the data to de DB.

```
<p:dialog header="Notas del Expediente" width="950"
            widgetVar="dialogNotaView" resizable="true"  minWidth="950"
            showEffect="slide" hideEffect="fade">                                                   
            <p:panelGrid columns="2" width="930">                       
                <p:panelGrid columns="1" width="75">
                    <p:commandLink title="Notas" onclick="return false;" style="margin:0 auto">
                    <center>
                      <p:graphicImage value="/images/nota.png"/>
                      </center>                                             
                        </p:commandLink>            
                           </p:panelGrid>                       
                              <p:panel id="panelViewNotas" header="Notas del Expediente" width="830">       
                              <center>  
                                <h:form id="formNotas">
                                <p:messages id="messagesNotas" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" />       
                                <p:panelGrid id="panelTabNotas" columns="2" width="800">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    Nota
                                </f:facet>
                                <p:graphicImage value="/images/nota.png" />
                                <h:outputText value="Nota" />
                                <h:outputText value="" />
                                <h:outputText value="" />

                                <h:outputText value="Nombre/Tema *" />
                                <p:inputText value="#{reporteConsultorBean.notaView.nombre}" required="false" requiredMessage="Es necesario que ingrese el asunto" 
                                                size="50" maxlength="49" />                                         
                                <h:outputText value="Descripción *" />
                                <p:inputTextarea value="#{reporteConsultorBean.notaView.descripcion}" rows="4" cols="65" maxlength="270"
                                                required="false" requiredMessage="Es necesario que ingrese la descripción de la nota." />       
                                </p:panelGrid>
                                <br/>
                                <p:panelGrid columns="2" >
                                <p:commandLink actionListener="#{reporteConsultorBean.saveNota}" 
                                                        update=":formMain:growl,:formMain:formNotasResult:panelResultadoNotas,:formMain:formNotas:panelTabNotas,:formMain:formNotas:messagesNotas" title="Guardar Nota" style="margin:0 auto"   >
                                <center>
                                <p:graphicImage value="/images/guardarBoton.png"/>
                                </center>                                           
                                </p:commandLink>
                                <p:commandLink title="Cerrar" onclick="dialogNotaView.hide(); return false;" style="margin:0 auto">
                                <center>
                                <p:graphicImage value="/images/cerrarBoton.png"/>
                                </center>                                           
                                </p:commandLink>
                                </p:panelGrid>
                                </h:form>   
                                <br/>
                                <p:separator style="width:700px;height:10px" /> 
                                <br/>
                                <h:form id="formNotasResult">
                                <p:panel id="panelResultadoNotas" header="Notas del Expediente" width="830">
                                  <p:dataTable id="tablaNotasResumen" var="notaResumen" 
                                                value="#{reporteConsultorBean.notasExp}" rowKey="#{notaResumen.idNota}"
                                                paginator="true" rows="4" emptyMessage="No hay registros"
                                                selectionMode="single"  selection="#{reporteConsultorBean.notaSelected}">                                           
                                    <p:column headerText="Nombre/Asunto">  
                                                  #{notaResumen.nombre}
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Descripción">                                               #{notaResumen.descripcion}
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Creador">  
                                                  #{notaResumen.actividad.creador}
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Fecha Creación">  
                                    <h:outputText value="#{notaResumen.actividad.fechaCreacion}">  
                                    <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy"/>
                                    </h:outputText>
                                    </p:column>                                                                     
                                    <p:column>
                                    <p:commandLink title="Editar Nota"  
                                                                update=":formMain:formNotas:panelTabNotas"
                                                                 action="#{reporteConsultorBean.editarNota(notaResumen)}">
                                            <p:graphicImage value="/images/editarBoton.png" />                                                        
                                    </p:commandLink>
                                   </p:column>
                            </p:dataTable>
                      </p:panel>
            </h:form>   
        </center>
        <br/>
</p:panel>
```

my problem comes when I use "panelViewNotas" in the button above. When I use it everything is displayed as it should, but when I hit the "Save" button on the last form, nothing happens (not even a nullPointerException in the Log or Tomcat).
and when I use:

```
update=":formMain:formNotasResult:panelResultadoNotas,:formMain:formNotas:panelTabNotas"
```

the data gets stored in the DB with no problem, but the View of the whole thing gets messed up "DialogNotaView" it shows one form in top of the other.

I hope you understand this problem and that u can help me.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Your code snippets are too long. Your problem seems straightforward enough but there's too much "stuff" here. Try to whittle it down to the smallest size possible to see the relevant elements only (this approach might also even help you resolve your problem on your own)

Comment: Well... I did try to make the snippets the smallest that I could. these are only the elements that are involved in my problem.
the problem is that I already everything I could come up with, with no good results, thats why I asked for help. Can you give me some opinions, or if you see something wrong in the code. specially on the update values??